# npm run script after pulling module from git

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a Node module whose source-code is in a Git repository (GitHub). I can install the module into an NPM project from Git using NPM:

```
npm install --save git@github.com:user/example.git
```

The problem is that there are some build steps that need to be done after pulling the source-code. I don't want to include the results of the build in Git because they are artefacts of the build step, not true source-code.

Currently, I need to manually move to the directory (`cd ./node_modules/example`) and then run the build script (`npm run build`), but this is a hassle.

Since everything is in NPM, can this be automated somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it from `postinstall` hook like so from the package.json that includes the module:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd ./node_modules/example && npm run build"
}
```

Here's a good resource on npm postinstall:

http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Fun-playing-with-npm-dependencies-and-postinstall-script

Comment: This script will be called every time when a new package is installed, not sure that this is good.

Comment: If you add this to the source package's package.json that gets pulled down as dependency, then it should not execute every time a new package is installed in the package where this package is being used. Makes sense?

Comment: unless you don't control the original package. In that case, just add a check in the build to ignore re-build.

Comment: Yes it makes sense, but only if you have access to this repo.

Comment: Exactly.  So if you don't have access to the source repo like I said, it would mean you are doing some custom building on that package for your own application. So it would make sense to move the building logic in your build script (grunt/gulp/whatever.. ) and just check whether it needs building. Post install would still be your best bet IMO